# How to find the equilibrium point of a system that is bowl shaped and a mass inside the bowl with given potential energy function?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, potential-energy, vector-fields, equilibrium, statics

**Question**: $z=U(x, y)=ax^2+by^2, (a,b \in R^+)$ is the potential energy function of the system. How to find the equilibrium point of  this system?

We have to find the equilibrium point of this system by using

$$F=-\frac{\partial U}{\partial \vec{r}}$$

If the system was in one dimension and the potential energy function would be $y=U(x)=ax^2$ then we would easily find the equilibrium point of that system by using $F=-\frac{\partial U}{\partial x}$ then we would find the roots of $F$ by $F=0$.

$$F=-\frac{\partial U}{\partial x}=-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(ax^2)=-2ax$$

$$F=-2ax=0 \Rightarrow x_0=0$$

I think the solution should be came by this way but I'm not sure how to solve that problem in 2 dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The force field $\mathbf E$ is given by the negative of gradient of the potential $V$ associated with that field. Mathematically

\begin{align}
\mathbf E&=-\nabla V\\
\mathbf E&=-\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial x} \mathbf{\hat i}+\frac{\partial V}{\partial y} \mathbf{\hat j}+\frac{\partial V}{\partial z} \mathbf{\hat k}\right)
\end{align}

Now you can easily solve the problem by finding the points where $\mathbf E=0$. These would be the points of equilibrium.

Note that the above formula can also be generalized to $n$-dimensions like this:

$$\mathbf E=-\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial V}{\partial q_i} \mathbf {\hat{e}_i}$$

where $q_i$ is $i$-th dimension and $\mathbf {\hat{e}_i}$ is the unit vector pointing in the direction of the $i$-th axis.

Answer (score 1):

In 2 dimensions, we use the gradient function. In Cartesian coordinates, it is given by $$\mathbf{F} = - \nabla U = 
- \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\text{d} F}{\text{d} x} \\ \frac{\text{d} F}{\text{d} y} \end{bmatrix}$$
Then you have to solve the 2 differential equations in order to obtain the equations of motion.

Answer (score 1):

The equilibrum point corresponds to the minimum or the maximum of the potential. To find it one needs to solve the equations obtained by setting all the partial derivatives of this potential to zero:
$$\mathbf{F} = \nabla\cdot\partial U(\mathbf{r}) = 0 \Leftrightarrow F_\alpha = \frac{\partial U(\mathbf{r})}{\partial x_\alpha}=0.$$